# MySQLで集計 カラムを検索した際のHIT数を取りたい

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
users
id | name
1  | tanaka
2  | suzuki
3  |  sato

articles
id|writer_1|writer_2|writer_3
1 |tanaka  |tanaka|tanaka
2 |suzuki  |sato    |tanaka
3 |suzuki  |suzuki  | sato
```

MySQLを使用しております。
上記のようなテーブルがあり、
usersのデータを取得する際に
「articlesテーブルのwriter_xカラムに自身のnameが何回出てくるか」
をSQLで集計することは可能でしょうか。
SQLの例も教えて頂けると助かります。

希望するレスポンスは以下です。

```
{
    name: tanaka,
    hitCount:4
},
{
    name : suzuki,
    hitCount:3 
},
{
    name : sato,
    hitCount:2 
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT writer, count(writer) FROM (
  SELECT writer_1 AS writer FROM articles
  UNION ALL
  SELECT writer_2 AS writer FROM articles
  UNION ALL
  SELECT writer_3 AS writer FROM articles
) a GROUP BY writer;

+--------+---------------+
| writer | count(writer) |
+--------+---------------+
| sato   |             1 |
| tanaka |             1 |
| yamada |             1 |
+--------+---------------+
(元のデータは再現してません)
```

このように同種のカラムを1つの行に複数持たせる(=列持ち)と検索や集計が単純にできなくなりますので、テーブル設計の典型的なアンチパターンとされています。可能であればテーブル設計を見直すことをお進めします。